# Why can't we use the toilet when the train isn't moving in some countries?

Tags: trains, legal, hygiene

I am not sure if the sign in the toilet said that we shouldn't use it if the train was not moving or that we shouldn't do so if the train was at the station.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I'm *sure* we've had this before, but I can't find it for the life of me.  As the answerer says tho, it's often as the toilet empties onto the tracks.

Comment: I can read the first language but in English, German and French, it does not say you should not use the toilets when the train is not moving, it says you should not use them when you are in a station, simply because it empties onto the tracks.

Comment: I remember this from early childhod.

Comment: The first language is Polish and essentially says the same as in the other languauges: It is prohibited to use the toilet when the train is standing at a station (na stacji).

Comment: it would be great to know where this photo was taken, these days.

Comment: @JoeBlow http://tinyurl.com/hdx2eve

Comment: It's quite bizarre that there's a wiki page on **"Passenger train toilet"** - heh!  Just FYI, @Ulkoma, that very page seems to totally and fully answer your question....

Comment: It also looks like that is the most likely source of Ulkomas image. Is that where you got it from?

Comment: @JoeBlow `these days` Eg. pretty much anywhere in Europe :D Sure, many of the newer trains don't eject it, but there are still a lot of old ones in use.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I googled the image, wasn't aware of the page till after you answered the question

Comment: nice google-technique!  good one

Comment: @JoeBlow The fact that the sign is written first in Polish strongly suggests that it's a Polish train, which would be used either in Poland (obviously) or on international trains to/from Poland. The only exception would be if the carriage had been recently sold to some other railway company and they'd not replaced the signage yet.

Comment: Fun fact: The German text should read `Während` and either `dem Bahnhof` or `den Bahnhöfen`. The Polish person writing that text should know that diacritics can change the meaning completely.

Comment: Here is a recently posted question on scifi.SE that is somewhat related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140569/why-were-they-not-allowed-to-use-this-seat-on-the-enterprise-while-in-a-spacedoc/140620

Comment: heh @DavidRicherby - that's a hell of a good point  :)

Comment: There's even a song: [Passengers will please refrain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poX6HDC5rNU)

Comment: I can't believe everybody forgot to add the tag [tag:hygiene].

Comment: the reason imho doesn't have to do with it actually being a toilet -- I believe it is so people without a train ticket don't hide in the toilets at stations where the controllers may check passenger tickets.

Comment: @FlorianCastellane to be honest this makes more sense than the other theory, would you care to put it as an answer please?

Comment: I do not think this has to do with it actually being a toilet -- It has to do with the fact that for people who are riding the train without a ticket, it is easy to hide in the toilets at stations when controllers come in so that it will not be discovered they don't have a ticket. At least it gives a basis for opening the door if someone just won't come out (which also makes sense for checking that the train is empty before it leaves its final station for the train hangars, etc).

Comment: There are multiple reasons I could think of: People without tickets could hide (but ticket control can happen anytime), your empty place is more likely to be taken by a new passenger, the train will eventually start to move again which might give you a hard time on the toilet.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I don't know specifically for the country you are in, but in many countries, this is because the toilet empties directly onto the tracks, even in countries with relatively modern trains. Even in the UK, some trains still do this (I found out when searching the Railway UK forums)

Another reason is because toilets on trains require pumps, and in the station there may not be sufficient spare power to allow the toilet to flush correctly.
This may be vacuum pressure or electric pump, depending on the type of train and toilet.

Comment: Please discuss this in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46916/discussion-on-answer-by-rory-alsop-why-cant-we-use-the-toilet-when-the-train-is).

Comment: First part is correct, the second one is not. Polish carriages with newer, "aircraft-style" toilets with closed system have plaques that explicitly state that they can be used at any time.

Comment: In the UK, Norwich to London trains are so old they still dump onto the tracks

Comment: As has been noted, some British trains still dump onto the tracks at the moment the flush is pressed. When I was a teenager (and before) some of the toilets on sub-urban trains were little more than just a seat over a hole through which you could see the track whizzing past below (not a pleasant experience to use, I might add). I'm not sure what Victorian train toilets were like (apart from relatively rare), but they too would have dumped directly on the track. I guess it's part of the tradition around here ;-)